# UIImagePicker custom name Images

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm creating a copy of the the image chosen through the UIImagePickerController.  What I need though is to prompt a user for an image name prior to duplicating and uploaded it to a webserver.  Anyone know the command to give the image a particular name/extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an custom alert which ask user for the image name, On click of "OK" button of alert view,  add the code to rename the image and then you can select the image to upload to server :

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(YourImage, 1.0);
NSString *path = NSDocumentDirectory();
NSString *tmpPathToFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg", path, specificImagedNameTakenFromUser]];

if([imageData writeToFile:tmpPathToFile atomically:YES]){
      //Write was successful. 
}
```

Now pick this image from the same location and upload to server.

Hope it will help.

Cheers.

Comment: are you appending the path and tmpPathtoFile backwards?

Comment: Ohhh, That was mistaken. Corrected Thanks for pointing it out.